# How to allow for some routes different maxRequestSize [NODE.JS]

Tags: node.js

How to allow for some routes different maxRequestSize [NODE.JS]

I wanna keep low maxRequestSize 100kb but for upload avatar i need 500kb for example.

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: config.maxRequestSize }))
```

Any suggestion ?